# How do I change the values in this array?

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

```
var array = [{"number":"500","title":"whatever 500"},{"number":"400","title":"whatever 400"}];

alert(array[0].number); //should output 500

$.each(array, function(index, val)
{
    array[index].number = val * 5;
});

alert(array[0].number); //should output 2500
```

I'm trying to multiply all the `numbers` in my array by 5. But for some reason it's not working. It outputs `NaN` (Not-a-Number). And when I try to add 50, it outputs `[object Object]50`.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that this code will give an error, because the second object doesn't have a terminating `}`. I imagine this is a copying error.

Comment: Yup, but thanks for pointing it out, anyway! I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `val` is the object, not a specific value from it.  So you're trying to multiply `{"number":"500","title":"whatever 500"}` by `5`, which unsurprisingly doesn't work.

You can just use `this` to refer to the current element in the loop. Your code might look like this:

```
$.each(array, function() {
    this.number = this.number * 5;
});
```

You could, in fact, make this even shorter, by using the [`*=` assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators):

```
$.each(array, function() {
    this.number *= 5;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is correct `each`:

```
$.each(array, function(index, val)
{
    array[index].number = val.number * 5;
});
```

You're iterating over the objects in array, because `array` contains objects. First `val` in your example equals to `{"number":"500","title":"whatever 500"}`

Answer (score -2):

"500" is not a number (NaN), it's a string.

Try with this array :

```
var array = [{"number":500,"title":"whatever 500"},{"number":400,"title":"whatever 400"];
```

Comment: No no no! There is no matter weather to multiply numbers or strings. `'10' * 5` equals to `10 * 5`